# How to detect NTFS mounted folders in C#?

Tags: c#, directory, ntfs, mount

Once upon a time I read how you detect programmatically for mounted NTFS folders (can cause cyclic recursion when searching through folders). Now i cannot find the link.. Does anyone know how to do this?

The mounting I am interested in detecting is when one folder is mounted to another folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean a [NTFS junction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point)? There is an [unmanaged API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364571(VS.85).aspx) to get the reparse point, which you then have to [interrogate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365511(VS.85).aspx) to see if it's actually a junction. This is all [available through P/Invoke](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/JunctionPointsNet.aspx), of course.

But, most folks just(1) look for [ReparsePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx) on the list of [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.attributes.aspx) returned by [DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7xk2b58.aspx).

(1) Note that a NTFS Junction is a *particular type of reparse point*, but not the only one. Symbolic links, <strike>hard links,</strike>(2) and any other user defined data are also reparse points.

(2) Whoops. Hard links aren't reparse points, [they're just standard directory entries pointing to the same file](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781134.aspx). Thanks to [Reuben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41646/reuben) for correcting me on that.

Comment: As Mark hints, "skipping" all reparse points during recursive directory enumeration can be a bad idea.  Depending on your context, it might be a wise idea to carefully exclude symlinks and junctions.

Also, a minor correction to Mark's comment--hard links are *not* implemented as reparse points.

Comment: @Reuben - You are correct, hard links are *not* reparse points. Edited and thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Do this via WMI. See sample at : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393244(VS.85).aspx

Or try this sample code made with [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en):

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WMISample
{
    public class MyWMIQuery
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", 
                    "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskPartition"); 

                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Win32_DiskPartition instance");
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Type: {0}", queryObj["Type"]);
                }
            }
            catch (ManagementException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```